# Exception binding blob in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I'm following tutorial on http://martinabbott.azurewebsites.net/2016/06/11/fun-with-azure-functions-and-the-emotion-api/

I have Blob Trigger Storage container named "pictures" in integration tab. myblob path is "pictures/{name}"   There are no input defined. Output is DocumentDB. I have verified that access key is correct.

I wonder what is reason for error? Connection problem to Azure Storage or cannot locate file for ?

Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerEmotionFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myBlob'. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing this exception because the blob container named `pictures` cannot be found in the storage account used by your Function App.  You have to create the blob container yourself as an out-of-band workflow.  This will allow Azure Functions to listen for any upload activity on the blob container.

You may download the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) client to create/confirm that the blob container `pictures` was created for the storage account tied to your Function app.  You can locate the storage account name and key by performing the following steps:

1. Visit the Functions Portal (using latest Runtime version ~0.9) for your Function app.
2. Click on **Function app settings->Configure app settings**.
3. Locate the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` or `AzureWebJobsStorage` settings value (whichever you chose when you created the Function), and lookup the `AccountName` and  `AccountKey` values.

A sample snapshot of a similar setup is shown below,

[image]

If the `pictures` container does not exist, you can use the Azure Storage Explorer client to create one.  Make sure that you choose either the `Public container`, or `Public blob` option.

Thanks for sharing the [tutorial](http://martinabbott.azurewebsites.net/2016/06/11/fun-with-azure-functions-and-the-emotion-api/).  It works for me. I hope this helps!